# Trying to assemble an IA32 assembly file and getting operand mismatch error for 'call'

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

Im trying to assemble an IA32 assembly file which reads the users input. When I try to run it with `as -o input.o input.s` I get an error saying "operand type mismatch for 'call'

Here is the code;

```
.code32
.section .rodata
output: .string "You entered %s\n"
inout: .string "%s"

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

subl $100, %esp
pushl $input
call scanf, %eax

add $8, %esp
pushl $output
call printf

xorl %eax, %eax
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has many errors. The particular one you asked about is because `call` only takes a single operand, the function (address) to call. It's unclear what you wanted to do with `call scanf, %eax` especially since you have not set `eax` to anything. `scanf` does take two arguments but even though you allocate a buffer on the stack you don't pass its address. `printf` as you use it also needs two arguments but you only pass the format string. Also you have a typo `inout` vs `input`. Furthermore you can not `ret` if you use `_start` as entry point, you need an `exit` system call. However if you intend to use C functions it's recommended to use `main` as entry point in which case you can keep the `ret`. A fixed version may look like:

```
.section .rodata
output: .string "You entered %s\n"
input: .string "%s"

.section .text
.globl main
main:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

subl $100, %esp
push %esp
pushl $input
call scanf

add $8, %esp
push %esp
pushl $output
call printf

xorl %eax, %eax
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Assemble and link using `gcc -m32 input.s`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems to be working however when I use gcc -m32 input.s to assemble it doesnt work. I've never used gcc before is there anything I need to use before han to get it to work?

Comment: there's lots of messages that appear, such as; cannot fint scrt1.o
cannot find crti.o
skipping incompatible 
cannot find -lgcc 
then finishes with ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Sounds like you don't have `gcc-multilib` installed and you are on a 64 bit system.

Comment: `apt-get install gcc-multilib` if you are on a debian based system. Note that using `.code32` will not make it a 32 bit program and if you ask for 32 bit output from `as`/`gcc` then the directive is unnecessary.

Comment: Right, I think I understand. Now that I've got multilib and I assemble using gcc -m32 input it seems to work, however when I then run the file with ./input I'm met with "Accessing a corrupt shared library"

Comment: Did you run `gcc -m32 -o input input.s`?

Comment: gcc -m32 -o input input.s does work! I managed to get it working in the end a different way Thank you so much for your help :)